# Excel - Using IF function to locate MAX and MIN numbers within a range

Tags: excel

I need help with creating an IF formula to locate MAX and MIN numbers within a range.

Looking at the Excel table snip below:

If I7 > 30, highlight MAX and MIN numbers within the range C7:E7

This will have to be a conditional formula so I can apply cell color

[image: Excel table]

Comment: So you have the logic correct, just apply conditional formatting twice ie once for max and once for min.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mike, but that is where I am stuck. I know the logic is correct. I am asking for help in writing a conditional formula for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually more tricky than I thought....

So try this:

For the MAX we use this formula:

```
=IF($I$7>30,B$7=MAX(B$7:E$7))
```

[image]

and for the MIN we use this formula:

```
=IF($I$7>30,B$7=MIN($B$7:$E$7))
```

[image]

Check that the conditional formatting applies to the expected range:
[image]

**Final Result**
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Your formulas worked Wizhi. For some odd reason I had to input them multiple times as the output was not working as expected, but eventually it worked. I also had to add in one additional rule because when no data is entered B7:E7 were always highlighted so I added in =$I$7=" " to the cells B7:E7 and everything is working the way I want now. Thank you for your help!